# Android jni "No Rule to make Target issue"

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile the project which i got from below link . 
[Github project fmpeg.](https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg)  But while compiling that to create .so files using andriod ndk version 5 i am getting the following issue . Please advice me to solve it .

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/D/Shakthi/jhotovy/jhotovy-android-ffmpeg-fab1412/Project/jni/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.c', needed by `/cygdrive/D/Shakthi/jhotovy/jhotovy-android-ffmpeg-fab1412/Project/obj/local/armeabi/objs/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.o'.  Stop.
```

My Android.mk file code.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE  := ffmpeg

FFMPEG_LIBS := $(addprefix ffmpeg/, \
 libavdevice/libavdevice.a \
 libavformat/libavformat.a \
 libavcodec/libavcodec.a \
 libavfilter/libavfilter.a \
 libswscale/libswscale.a \
 libavutil/libavutil.a \
 libpostproc/libpostproc.a )

OGG_LIBS := $(addprefix libogg/output/lib/, \
 libogg.a )

VORBIS_LIBS := $(addprefix libvorbis/output/lib/, \
 libvorbis.a \
 libvorbisenc.a \
 libvorbisfile.a )

THEORA_LIBS := $(addprefix libtheora/output/lib/, \
 libtheora.a \
 libtheoraenc.a \
 libtheoradec.a )

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -Iffmpeg -Ivideokit -Wno-deprecated-declarations 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz $(FFMPEG_LIBS) $(THEORA_LIBS) $(OGG_LIBS) x264/libx264.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg_android/ffmpeg_android.c ffmpeg/ffmpeg.c ffmpeg/cmdutils.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# Use to safely invoke ffmpeg multiple times from the same Activity
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeginvoke

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg_invoke/ffmpeg_invoke.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions in ["How to build it"](https://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg/blob/master/README.textile)?

Comment: how can i do it in android . they are looks like desktop commands.

Comment: You are not building the library _on_ your android device are you?

Comment: From README.texile:
    Run ./init-submodules.sh to pull in the FFMPEG and libx264 submodules.
    cd Project/jni
    do export NDK=~/apps/android-ndk-r5c using the actual path of your Android NDK.
    Run ./create_toolchain.sh to install a local copy of the standalone toolchain

Did you execute the above commands before attempting to build?

Comment: not yet wojci .. i have to do these things in my windows comdprompts?

Comment: It looks like the author of the library assumes that you use git and Linux. I don't use windows so I cannot help you there. :(

Comment: k .. it will work on linux virtual box...? if it is i will install it soon

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14122/discussion-between-rajesh-and-wojci)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use a virtual machine with Linux in order to build the lib.

Comment: yeah im just installing it ... i have installed the gitbash.. using that can i do anything to build the project